Bash tilde expansion not working when attached to a quoted string
echo ~/"foo"

Works as expected - you get
/home/<username>/foo

However, if the forward slash is moved inside the quoted area
echo ~"/foo"

expansion does not work anymore. You get
~/foo

What is the rule that is controlling such behaviour?

That quotes suppress tilde expansion? That's right there in black-letter documentation. You already know the rule: your question describes it; I don't know what more there is to say.

(The word "unquoted" is right there in the "If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character" at the beginning of the Tilde Expansion section of the manual).

"If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character" - in both cases this is true but the result is different.
I do not see where my question is answered in the given above "duplicate" question.

Still, you understand the actual behavior so you don't have a question with an answer expected to change how you go about the practice of software development.

(if you look up the docs I quoted from, you'll see that a few words past the end of the quote it refers to "the first unquoted slash"; thus it's also black-letter documentation that the slash needs to be unquoted as well).

...I can edit the duplicate question's answer to cover that explicitly, if it'll help. (That question was built with the intent of being a canonical dupe target, so this kind of edit is very much in-keeping with same).

As for the rationale for this being the actual behavior -- things in quotes are data (subject to explicit, clear exceptions only available for double quotes), whereas things outside quotes can be syntax. When someone writes ~user/, the fact that they wanted tilde expansion is authorial intent -- it's syntax; you don't want a variable with content that's expected to start with a / but instead contains othername/ to change from the current user's home directory to someone else's, for example.

Thank you @CharlesDuffy for explanation, but I must say I do not find supporting statements by reading the manual literally.
The "first unquoted slash" is used to detect tilde-prefix and the possible login name "If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted".
"thus it's also black-letter documentation that the slash needs to be unquoted as well" -  this is simply not true, if it is there and not quoted it will be used as a demarcation character, but nothing mandatory.
There is probably no use in continuing this discussion since we know the actual behavior and read the spec.

What I see as an issue now is that my question has been closed without proper justification by referring to a similar-looking but not, in essence, a duplicate question. You could just as well have referred to any other tilde-expansion related post
